# Using static/global variables as default arguments

Tags: c++, static, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, default

I came up with a solution when dealing with methods/functions with default arguments **passed by value**, but I'm not sure if it approach can be problematic.

When the desired behavior is to have a single value as a default argument, just specifying a value is enough:

```
void foo(type arg=value)
{
    //do something using arg...
}
```

But when the desired behavior is to do generate a random value, for example, things differ. In this case, to generate a random value, I came up with the given solution:

```
static type DEFAULT = /* value */; //static is optional, DEFAULT can be any name.
void foo(const type& arg=DEFAULT)
{
    type x;
    if(&arg == &DEFAULT)
        x = generate_random();
    else x = arg;
    // also we could use a ternary like
    // type x = (&arg == &DEFAULT? generate_random() : arg) 

    // do something with x...
}
```

Are there any drawbacks to using this approach? Can a reference's address be safely compared with the given default argument's address? Will this also work with methods and static class variables?

Some other solutions are:

Overload with an **additional signature**:

```
void foo(){ /* do something using a random value */  }

void foo(type arg){ /* do something using arg... */ }
```

Or maybe *pointers* instead, and default *arg* with null:

```
void foo(type* arg=null) { /* if arg is null, generate value.  */ }
```

Comment: In your case, isn't it much better to overload the function in case the argument is not passed? Indeed, that's what should be done. A default value is a default value, not a default behavior.

Comment: @GabrielVasconcelos I see your point. However I've seen functions that receive pointers and have a distinct behavior when null pointers are passed (not just throwing exceptions). [SDL's FillRect](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_FillRect) function have a slightly different behavior when passing NULL to its second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why you want to make it so complicated. As a user of this function I would not expect it to work as it does. If the signature is

```
void foo(const type& arg=DEFAULT);
```

Then I would expect the following two calls to be equivalent:

```
foo();
type x = DEFAULT;
foo(x);
```

The problem is not to take the adress of the reference. The reference is just an alias for the original variable. The problem is that you expect the variable `DEFAULT` instead of its value. This is not how function parameters are expected to work (even if it is pass-by-reference).

Btw, the example above is not too contrived. Just imagine I want to put parameters in a vector and then call the function for each element in the vector. With your current approach I cannot put the `DEFAULT` inside the vector and pass it to the function. Actually it is even worse: I can do it, but it will not do what I expect.

In this paricular case I would simply implement it like this:

```
void foo(T arg = 0, bool generateRandom = true) {
    T x;
    if(generateRandom) x = generate_random();
    else x = arg;

    // do something with x...
}
```

Then it can be called like this:

```
foo(3.5,false); // uses the value
foo();          // generates a random value
```

Comment: The name DEFAULT was just an example. It can be chosen to avoid name collisions.

Comment: `will not be recognized as DEFAULT`. That is actually intended. If a value is specified, it should be behave as if the user has specified a value.

Comment: @Hydren well, then I misunderstood the snippet. However, I still dont understand why you want to make it complicated. Would'nt it be even easier to let the user pass a randomly generated value if he wants the function to use one? If I was a user I would like to be able to inspect the random value that was used.

Comment: @Hydren changed the answer, actually my argumentation is still the same, dont do it ;)

Comment: It is more of a theoretical question. I wanted to know if the comparison could go wrong due to being a global or static class variable's address comparison.

Comment: In my tests, it works (gcc and MSVC2010). I wanted to know if I could avoid using function/method overload and avoid using pointers in this case.

Comment: @Hydren well, the comparison is fine, because the reference really is the original variable just with a different name, ie it is just an alias. However, there are lots of things that one can do that make code less understandable and less useable. Dont you agree that it is a big drawback, that once you put the "default value" in a vector (or any other container) it does not work anymore?

Comment: Yes, using the default variable directly should give problems. But only if using the *variable*, its *value* can perfectly be used given that it comes from **another variable**.

Comment: what i mean is: if I pass the default variable i get the default behaviour, but if I pass the default value (which will be the case when I push the default variable in a container) then I dont get default behaviour. Thats not just less readable, but very confusing imho

Comment: What do you think if the default variable is not accessible, i.e. is private?

Comment: even worse. I think you didnt get the point. As a user I want to put the parameters in a vector to call the funciton inside a loop and for some iterations I want to have the default. How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: I agree that the default variable leads to some inconsistency, like your example about passing the default variable's value to a vector and not getting the default behavior, but that's it. The default behavior would not be achievable through some value. For example, if one would use function overload instead, one would need to call `foo()` to get the default behavior. You see, calling `foo(3.5)` from your example's foo() doesn't exactly make sense.